# e-learning in unity would it be possible to set lessons using unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are currently developing an e-learning system and we are using unity. It is included in our features that the teacher can set specific sets of lessons and exercises for that certain child she is teaching. We created pre-defined lessons and exercises categorized by age in unity like puzzle games, etc. If the child she is teaching is aged 4, the lessons and exercises the teacher could give the child are those that were created for age 4. Would it be possible to implement that? and would you give us any ideas on how we would be able to implement it.

Comment: "Would it be possible?" Considering that making "that" is *my full time job* and involves 12 other people (at a minimum) I would say "yes." Can you do it solo? No idea. What steps are needed? That's too broad. But the baseline "is this possible" question is always going to be (a completely useless) "yes."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. But it depend on the size of your team and the final build platform. however you can have multiple approach.

First the structure of the project

- App alone : So the teacher has to set-up each station at the beginning of the exercise.
- App + Back end + Server : each student can log get there info. The teacher can see the progression and prepare each session before it begin.

After how it can work in the app:

- If you choose App alone you put everything in your app each exercise and if you have to add an other exercise that wasn't in the build you have to recreate a build.
- If you have a server and big structure you can implement your exercise with asset bundle or with addressable asset.
- If you identified all the type of gameplay, you implement them and a system that load data from a server.